# Вызвать хранимую процедуру и получить строку символов

Tags: oracle, php

Как правильно вызвать хранимую процедуру и получить строку символов из базы Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.askit.ru/custom/oracle10sql/m19/lab19_02.htm